# Setting up Django Form Wizard

Tags: python, django, django-formwizard, formwizard

I'm attempting to set up a Django Form Wizard, but I'm having trouble getting it to work. I've followed the example, from the Django website, but can't get anything to work. When I go to the URL that should have my multistep form, only the template html thats extended shows up. What am I doing wrong here?

**FORMS.PY**

```
    class ScheduleDate(forms.Form):
        date = forms.CharField()

    class ScheduleTime(forms.Form):
        time = forms.CharField()
```

**VIEWS.PY**

```
    FORMS =[('date', ScheduleDate),
         ('time', ScheduleTime)]

    TEMPLATES = [('date', 'main/schedule_date2.html'),
         ('time', 'main/schedule_time.html')]


    class ContactWizard(SessionWizardView):
        def get_template_name(self):
            return TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]

        def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
            print 'testing'
            return HttpResponseRedirect('main/home.html')
```

**URLS.PY**

```
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^checkout/$', views.ContactWizard.as_view([ScheduleDate,    ScheduleTime]), name='checkout'))
```

**SCHEDULE_DATE2.HTML(From the Django Website)**

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}
    {% load i18n %}

    {% block head %}
    {{ wizard.form.media }}
    {% endblock %}

    {% block content %}
    <p>Step {{ wizard.steps.step1 }} of {{ wizard.steps.count }}</p>
    <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
   <table>
   {{ wizard.management_form }}
   {% if wizard.form.forms %}
        {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
        {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
            {{ form }}
        {% endfor %}
   {% else %}
        {{ wizard.form }}
  {% endif %}
   </table>
  {% if wizard.steps.prev %}
    <button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.first    }}">{% trans "first step" %}</button>
    <button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">{% trans "prev step" %}</button>
    {% endif %}
   <input type="submit" value="{% trans "submit" %}"/>
  </form>
  {% endblock %}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does "only the template html thats extended shows up" mean? What *exactly* are you seeing?

Comment: Just my base template, which I assume is from "{% extends "base.html" %} "

Comment: And what does that look like? Does it have blocks for `head` and `content`?

Comment: It has all the content inherited from the "{% extends "base.html" %}", but nothing else. To get to this point, I actually had to create this html file in formtools/wizard/wizard_form.html. I had to do this because the get_template_name method didn't work, and required me to create a template in formtools/wizard.

Comment: That's not what I asked. Does the base template define "head" and "content" blocks?

Comment: Oh wow. I completely forgot to change that, when I copied over the template from the django website. Thank you!